# Update first table column with another table's values in Spark SQL using HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I want to update a column in my existing table by overwriting that column from another table.

Example: There is the column `name` in table `student`, but there is another table `employee` and I want to overwrite column `name` of the `student` table by column `name` from the `employee` table. I want to do this in Spark SQL using HiveContext.

Can we run this command:

```
insert overwrite table stud (name) select name from table employee
```

in Spark using HiveContext?